# how to call the google map from my android application like invoke the email

Tags: android, maps

```
try {
        Intent searchAddress = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("geo:0,0?="+emp_city_location));
        startActivity(searchAddress);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

i got the exception like

03-03 21:01:56.349: INFO/System.out(179): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?=chennai }

please do reply me

Comment: Bro.. when you are posting your code, please try to format it properly.. coz it will take a bit more time to understand...

Answer (score 3):

You need to construct your `geo:` URL properly. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) for the syntax. I think you may only be missing a `q` between the `?` and the `=`, but I have not tried that particular `geo:` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are using the Google API emulator image for your testing.  Bring up the AVD and set the emulator to be a Google API emulator.  If you don't do this, then you will continue to get the bug.  Also, the previous poster was right... you need to following the URI standards found here:  http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Have declared Activity in manifest file also check have you added Google map library in manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
geo:0,0?q=chennai
```