# Xamarin: open Google Maps App from a Android WebView App

Tags: google-maps, android-activity, webview, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have created a WebView App with VS2015 / Xamarin.
The WebView loads an external webiste (the pages are not included in the APP).
One of the website pages contains an html link of this kind:

```
<a href="geo:42.374260,-71.120824">
```

I would like to make sure Android opens Google Maps App when a user clicks on the link.
I have made use of ShouldOverrideUrlLoading in this way:

```
public class WebClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
            {

                //Click on a georeferenced link
                if (url.IndexOf("geo:")>-1)
                {
                    var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("geo:42.374260,-71.120824");
                    var mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, geoUri);
                    StartActivity(mapIntent);
                    return true;
                }

                //Click on a generic link
                view.LoadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Now, problem is, the StartActivity line returns an error: *An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ContextWrapper.StartActivity(Intent)'*

Could you suggest which is the right syntax I should use to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem.
The right way of calling StartActivity is the following:

```
 if (url != null && url.IndexOf("geo:")>-1)
                {
                    var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
                    var mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, geoUri);
                    view.Context.StartActivity(mapIntent);
                    return true;
                }
```

An interesting thread on the topic is to be found here: [How to handle geo: links in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274871/how-to-handle-geo-links-in-webview)

Comment: Is there a possible to set a pin to the map?